# Cardinality of quotient group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-modules

I have a question.

$G$ is a free abelian group with rank $m$.
$A \subset B$ are both subgroups of $G$ with rank $m$, but $A \neq B$.

Why is the inequality $|G /B| < |G /A|$ correct?

Thank you for the time and effort!

Comment: @Bernard The end of that line makes that clear.

Comment: @DonAntonio: right. I didn't read the end of line. Shame on me! :-(

Comment: @Bernard Welcome to the club. I'm honorary president for life...

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. Prove that if $G$ is free abelian of rank $m$ and $A$ is a rank $m$ subgroup of $G$ then $G/A$ is finite.
2. Prove that if $A\lneq B$ then $\phi: G/A\twoheadrightarrow G/B$ in a natural way, and $\ker\phi\neq1$.
3. Combine 1. and 2. to prove your result.

Comment: Are you saying $\;\phi\;$ is surjective (double arrow notation) and **also** injective (since $\;\ker\phi=1\,$) ? So $\;\phi \;$ is an isomorphism and thus you proved $\;\left|G/A\right|=\left|G/B\right|\;$ ...I think you meant something else...and a more or less natural map exists, if I am not misunderstanding something, the other direction around.

Comment: Well, in fact "natural" is way an overstatement in this case (the one I mentioned in my comment above, that is) . There is *some* rather non-natural monomorphism $\;G/B\to G/A\;$ but it can be done in several ways, none of them prefarable over the other ones. For example, with $\;A=4\Bbb Z\subset 2\Bbb Z=B\;$ , yet a monomorphism $\;\phi:\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ can be realized in two different ways.

Comment: @DonAntonio The $=1$ should have been $\neq1$. Edited now.

Comment: @DonAntonio However...my map is pointing the right way. For example, $G=\langle a, b: [a, b]\rangle$, $A=\langle a^2\rangle$, $B=\langle a\rangle$. Then $C_{\infty}\times C_2\cong G/A\twoheadrightarrow G/B\cong C_{\infty}$. I don't see what is "unnatural" about this map - it is simply the map $gA\mapsto gB$ for all $g\in G$. (I believe I am correct, but I happy to be shown to be incorrect. The direction of the arrow gave me a headache, but I am still sure that it is correct.)

Comment: I understand the typo $\;\neq1\;$ ...and that's all. About natural: it is fine since now I see you actually meant the natural epimorphism (I myself used that in my answer), but when I thought you meant a monomorphism then that'd go in the opposite direction, of course...and thus it isn't natural anymore. BTW, one of the upvotes to your question is mine as I think it is a nice way to answer questions.

Comment: @DonAntonio Also...there is a unique monomorphism $C_2\rightarrow C_4$ as $C_4$ has a unique element of order two. There are two from $C_3$ to $C_6$ because of the automorphisms of $C_3$; is that what you are getting at?

Comment: (@DonAntonio I appreciate the dialogue and I wasn't talking your comments negatively. I hope you were not taking mine negatively.)

Comment: Yes. that's what I was getting...and of course, I wasn't taking your comments negatively. Not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\;\phi: G/A\to G/B\;,\;\;\phi gA:=gB\;$

The above is well defined since $\;gA=hA\implies h^{-1}g\in A\subset B\implies gB=hB\;$ , it's clearly a homomorphism of groups which is also trivially an epimorphism.

Choose now $\;b\in B\setminus A\;$ . Then $\;bA\neq A\;$, but $\;bB=B\;$ , and this implies $\;\phi\;$ cannot be injective (since $\;\ker\phi\neq1\;$ ...) . Finitiness of the quotient groups finishes now the proof.